# How can I retrieve image from Active Directory?

Tags: image, active-directory, base64, salesforce

I'm trying to retrieve the thumbnailPhoto attribute from the Active Directory, convert it to Base64 and then update a field in Salesforce with it. But as you can see from the image below, the image is not found:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
 output_row.Id = input_row.Id;
 output_row.UserPhotoLoader__User_Photo_Blob__c = null;


 File file = new File("C:/Desktop/Studio/workspace/" + 
 input_row.thumbnailPhoto + ".jpg");


try {           
    FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte imageData[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    imageInFile.read(imageData);
    imageInFile.close();

output_row.UserPhotoLoader__User_Photo_Blob__c = "<img alt=\"" + input_row.Name + "\" src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," +
                        new String(Base64.encodeBase64(imageData)) +
                        "\"></img>";

System.out.println("+++ Conversion réussie pour " + input_row.Name);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("*** Image non trouvée pour " + input_row.Name + "\n" + e);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
System.out.println("*** Erreur de lecture de l'image " + input_row.Name + "\n" + ioe);
}
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: This code is just reading an image from a file. Do you have other code that has already read the `thumbnailPhoto` attribute and saved it to that file?

Comment: No that's my only code...Ok so I need to save the attribute thumbnailPhoto to the file I created before then

Comment: No, you don't necessarily have to save it to a file first. If you are just going to base64 encode it and put it in an `img` tag, then I don't see a reason to save it to a file. I just don't see where you have read the `thumbnailPhoto` attribute. What type is `input_row`?